# In NVD3 chart how can i use custom tooltip along with having userInteractiveGuideLine true

Tags: nvd3.js, angular-nvd3, angularjs-nvd3-directives, ng2-nvd3

I am using nvd3 to plot some chart. I want to show a custom tooltip instead of the default tooltip provided by nvd3. At the same time i want to show the guideline to i.e. the vertical guide line bar.
But the problem is when i show the custom tooltip i have to disable the userInteractiveGuideLine.The following code shows what i am actually want

```
useInteractiveGuideline: false,
tooltip: {
       contentGenerator: function(e) {
         console.log("TOOLTIP entered");
        /*Details code here*/
           }
}
```

So when i make `useInteractiveGuideline: false` I can see the custom tooltip and can see the custom message `TOOLTIP entered` but i cant see the vertical guideLine. But when u set `useInteractiveGuideline: true` i can see the vertical guide line but i cant see the custom tooltip. I cant see the console message also.
Is there any solution that i can use custom tooltip along with using `useInteractiveGuideline: true`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `callback` to provide custom tooltip with interactiveUserGuideLine

```
callback: function(chart) {
                var tooltip=chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip;
                tooltip.contentGenerator(function(d) {
                      //Do custom toltip code here and return
                    });
                return chart;
            },
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, this is how I create custom tooltip, but no guideline

`code
            useInteractiveGuideline: false,
            tooltip: {
              contentGenerator: e => tooltipTemplate(e)
            },
`
I also tried with the callback, and no luck.

`code
            callback: (chart) => {
              const tooltip = chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip;
              tooltip.contentGenerator((e) => {
                return tooltipTemplate(e);
              });
              return chart;
            },
`